# Choosing between the UpnName and SmtpAddress for the X-AnchorMailbox header when using Office 365 REST API

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

We use the Outlook REST API with Azure AD authentication to access mailboxes of our users. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api) recommends the use of the `x-AnchorMailbox` header to optimize performance :

> For optimal performance when using the new Outlook REST endpoint, add an x-AnchorMailbox header for every request and set it to the user's email address. For example: x-AnchorMailbox:john@contoso.com

For a given user, should we use the **primary SMTP Address** (which may change) or the **UPN Name** for this purpose ?

There are various code samples using these techniques (like [this](https://github.com/jasonjoh/dotnet-tutorial/blob/5f269ea41495c3ef20ebab7f3c37cde4745d748d/dotnet-tutorial/Controllers/HomeController.cs)), however it uses an `EmailAddress`, which can be ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be setting this to the `EmailAddress` property of the user (obtained from the `/Me` endpoint of the API.